# How do you get latitude and longitude co-ordinates on iOS 8 and iPhone 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

Since iOS 8 I can't access GPS co-ordinates on my phone. I have done the following:

// This has now been edited to show working code thanks to the posts

1. Added CoreLocation.framework on project creation.
2. Added the following keys to my .plist file

   ```
   <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
   <string></string>
   //<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
   //<string></string>
   ```
3. Added header calls

   ```
   import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

   @interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

   @property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

   @end
   ```
4. Added to the main file

   ```
   //define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

   - (void)viewDidLoad {

       [super viewDidLoad];

       self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

       self.locationManager.delegate = self;

       // Both work
       //[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

       //if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
           [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
       //}

       self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

       [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
   }
   ```

I get no authorisation alert prompt and have tried many of the solutions provided but none have worked. Can anyone help with a proven live project? [SOLVED]

THE PROBLEM WAS UPGRADING OF XCODE NOT THE CODE.

Comment: What you're doing is very scattershot. You only need (and can only have) one kind of authorization. Decide which you need and think logically about how / when to ask for it. Finally, _always_ end by attempting to start updating location; if you fail, you'll fall in good order into the Failed delegate event.

Comment: And please spend a little time learning to format Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: And if you're going to call `requestAlwaysAuthorization`, then your plist needs `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` description. But right now you request "in use" authorization twice and "always" authorization once. Request one authorization, and request once. Also, what is `authorizationStatus`? If `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied`, it won't ask the user again: You have to go to settings and change that setting and there's nothing you can do programmatically other than tell the user that. Also, you're testing this on actual device, right?

Comment: And do you have an actual value for the when in use description key?  You can't have an empty string - you have to give the reason that you want to use location

Comment: Thanks Rob for picking up the plist and command mismatch as well as the authorisation issue. I added the plist entry and replaced my if statement and its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your plist

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

And this code

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)


    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
            [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        }
```

This worked for me. Hope will work for you too :)

Comment: Good answer, but you shouldn't use compile-time check of the OS version (because you may compile for iOS 7 and later and you won't know what version the device is actually using until run-time). Use `if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) ...` run-time check.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your plist file, you need to supply an actual string:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

You can't have an empty string there.